# Non-selenium way to download data from Web using R/Python

Tags: python, r, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, rvest

I am looking for some non-Selenium way to mine data from a Website using `R` (preferably) or `Python`.

In R I used below code to do the same-

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
Link = 'https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/itc-ltd/itc/500875/'
read_html(Link) %>% html_nodes(".textvalue .ng-binding") %>% html_text()
## character(0)
```

Ideally I should be able to get most of the numerical values. But as you see it could not be able to download anything. Any pointer towards the right approach will be highly beneficial.

I also tried with *`BeautifulSoup module`* from `Python` as below without any success-

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
uClient = uReq("https://www.bseindia.com/stock-share-price/itc-ltd/itc/500875/")
page_html = uClient.read()
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"textvalue.ng-binding"})
```

Thanks,

Comment: Try beautiful soup or scrapy

Comment: @Paula - BeautifulSoup doesnt seem to be able to fetch the data

Comment: There are quite a few numerical values on the website could you please tell me which one precisely are you seeking to get

Comment: @Bogaso Which data are you trying to extract from the page? The page is full of AngularJS calls and therefore you will not be able to extract the data without using a mechanism that is javascript capable. Why don't you want to use selenium?

Comment: @PaulaLivingstone This isn't necessarily always the case, even thought the site is javascript based. Often times the data is sent in the form a JSON string (which can be easily collected using requests)

Comment: Yeah fair point

Comment: I intend to pick the number "2,56,190.08" which corresponds to Mcap FF (Cr.) I would like to use Selenium as the last resort as it is Resource heavy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy as you can use the API the page uses. The return json has all the values but I am printing only one.

**Python:**

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/StockTrading/w?flag=&quotetype=EQ&scripcode=500875').json()
print(r['MktCapFF'])
```

---

**R:**

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)

r <- read_html('https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/StockTrading/w?flag=&quotetype=EQ&scripcode=500875') %>%html_text() %>%jsonlite::fromJSON(.)
print(r$MktCapFull)
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks

Comment: Hi QHarr, is there any API availability to extract the 'PE' as well?

Comment: Have you checked the Json returned?

Comment: Yes, this API doesnt seem to be retuning values for PE